# JQueryUI with Google's CDN issue

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, cdn

I'm having trouble loading JQueryUI from Google's CDN. I've got an ASP.NET application that and am using this to call the scripts:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

I then have a test accordion:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't work. I used Chrome's Dev tool and I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: The 'accordion' plugin requires
>   Sys.scripts.ExtendedAccordion to be loaded with a call to
>   Sys.require() first

I'm also using MS' Ajax CDN in my masterpage, so could that be causing a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a conflict between the MS Ajax oolkit accordion and the jQuery UI accordion.  Can you remove the Ajax Toolkit?

Comment: I've been trying to remove the AJAX Toolkit and shift to JQuery, but there are still quite a few pages using the toolkit (through the MS AJAX CDN). Will the conflict only be resolved if I remove all the Ajax Toolkit components? thanks

Comment: Try using jQuery in noConflict mode and referencing the accordion plugin using jQuery() instead of $().

Comment: I gave that a shot, but it doesn't seem to work. I'll remove any of the other MS Ajax dependencies first and then come back to this.
Thanks for the help